# Problem in saving result of HTML <select> in groovy

Tags: html, groovy

I have a question in saving a result of HTML select in groovy. If I run the below codes, only "Zimbabwe" is saved whatever I select.

```
a.add(v,
            [name: "Submit",
             custom: """

<p><strong><u><font size = "4"> What is your nationality? </font size></u></strong></p>
    <div>
    <select name = "nation">
      <option type = "select" class = "param" name = "nation" label for "AF">Afghanistan </option>
      <option type = "select" class = "param" name = "nation" label for="AX">Åland Islands</option>
      <option type = "select" class = "param" name = "nation" label for="AL">Albania</option>
      <option type = "select" class = "param" name = "nation" label for="DZ">Algeria</option>
      <option type = "select" class = "param" name = "nation" label for="AS">American Samoa</option>
      <option type = "select" class = "param" name = "nation" label for="AD">Andorra</option>
      <option type = "select" class = "param" name = "nation" label for="AO">Angola</option>
      <option type = "select" class = "param" name = "nation" label for="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
      <option type = "select" class = "param" name = "nation" label for="AR">Argentina</option>
      <option type = "select" class = "param" name = "nation" label for="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
    </select>
</div>

""".toString(),

       result: { params->
         a.addEvent("RangeEvent", 
                    ["pid":v.id,
                     "nation": params['nation']
                    ]
                   )
       }])
```

I expected an abbreviation such as "AF" or "AX" would be saved, but it was not. Is there any problem in this script? If you need more detailed code, please let me know.

Comment: Can you try removing the `name` attribute from the options tags?

Comment: there should be `value` attribute like this: `<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>`. check documentation https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

Comment: @tim_yates Thank you for your comments. I solved the problem. Attributes should be inside of <select> not <option>.

Comment: @daggett Thank you for your comments. I solved the problem. Attributes should be inside of <select> not <option>.